# How to backup these files into specific folders using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, backup, hashtable

I've finally have given up googling and come here out of desperation. Go easy on me I'm fairly new to Powershell.

So, the objective of the code below was to first look through the source folder, then read through each .zip file and move to the directory specified by the value in the hashtable. Unfortunately, this is not how they want it to work anymore.

Now I need to retain the parent folder from source: for example "DAL" and then create the proceeding folders based on the file names and finally move each .zip to its file specified folder. Also, it needs to go through each folder under source which will be at least 20 other folders with a unique 3 character names.

```
 $srcRoot = "C:\Cloud\source\dal"
    $dstRoot = "C:\Cloud\Destination"

    ##$map = @{}; dir -recurse | ? { !$_.psiscontainer} | % { ##$map.add($_.name,$_.PSChildName) }

# DAT and DEV will have to be excluded from folder creation 
    $map = {
    #AEODDAT_201901 = "AEOD\2019\01"
    #AEOMDEV_201902 = "AEOM\2019\01"
    #AEOYDAT_201902 = "AEOY\2019\01"
    }

    $fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -Filter "*.zip*" -File -Force -Recurse
    foreach ($file in $fileList)
    {
        #Go through each file up to mapped string
        $key = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,14)
        if ($key -in $map.Keys)
        {
            $fileName = $file.Name
            $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath $map[$key]
            #create direcotory if not in path
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir))
            {
                mkdir -Path $dstDir
            }
            Write-Verbose "Moving $($file.FullName)"
            if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName))
            {
            #Write error if name exists
                Write-Error -Message "File $fileName already exists at $dstDir"
            #move path
            } else {
                Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstDir 
            }
        }
    }
```

So C:\Cloud\source\DAL\AEODDAT20190101.zip should create folders in C:\Cloud\Destination\DAL\AEOD\2019\01\AEODDAT20190101.zip would be my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Matt! (no pun intended) One of the habits I have in similar situations with destination folders is to `Set-Location $dstRoot` and create folders from the relative path. You can execute `New-Item` with the relative path and the syntax is simpler. For example, your `If` statement could look like this and it would work the same way (with a slightly different error message):

```
if ($key -in $map.Keys){
  Set-Location $dstRoot
  New-Item -ItemType Directory $map[$key] -ErrorAction Ignore #won't raise an error if it exists
  Write-Verbose "Moving $($file.FullName)"
  #this will raise an error if the file already exists, unless you specify -Force
  Move-Item "$($file.FullName)" $map[$key]
}
```

EDIT: Found 2 issues.

1. `$map` is a Hashtable literal that should be preceded with `@`:
     `$map = @{
        AEODDAT20190101 = "AEOD\2019\01"`
2. You were missing the last character of the base file name by taking only the first 14 characters. AEODDAT2019010 didn't match AEODDAT20190101. This should fix it: 
   `$key = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,15)`

Comment: Thank you. There is nothing wrong with the current code that I have now. I just need it to copy the folder name of the .zip files and then create that folder in the new destination path. Including the AEOD\2019\01\*.zip

Comment: All the values in your `$map` hashtable are currently commented out (`#`). The comment, 'DAT and DEV will be excluded...'  seems to indicate this is by design. But your comment '...\AEOD**DAT**20190101.zip would be my desired output.'  is inconsistent. 
I suggest uncommenting a `$map` entry, or adding a new entry to the `$map` from an existing ZIP file, to see if you get the desired output.

Comment: I left that in there as an example of what I have done with Hashtables. Sorry if it was confusing. The hashtable will no longer work for me as far as I know.

Comment: Try the two changes after EDIT. It worked in my test.